# Can I use field variable in Android sync adapter which will be modified by the onperform sync method?

Tags: android, thread-safety, background-process, android-syncadapter

I have an Android Sync adapter to push the local data to server using volley request. I am using a integer variable lastid for checking that last synced data row. Is it okay to use a variable in syncadapter which may be modified by the onPerformSync method? does it affect the sync if sync adapter is handling parellel request? I have some random missing of data in syc process? Can anyone please help me with this?

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

 // Define a variable to contain a content resolver instance
    ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    Context ctx;
    SQLiteDatabase syncdb=null;
    SQLiteDatabase mydbsalesdata=null;
    private String TAG="syncadapter";
    String lastid;

    /**
     * Set up the sync adapter
     */
    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        ctx=context;
        /*
         * If your app uses a content resolver, get an instance of it
         * from the incoming Context
         */
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the sync adapter. This form of the
     * constructor maintains compatibility with Android 3.0
     * and later platform versions
     */
    public SyncAdapter(
            Context context,
            boolean autoInitialize,
            boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
        super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
        /*
         * If your app uses a content resolver, get an instance of it
         * from the incoming Context
         */
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

        /*
         * Put the data transfer code here.
         */

        if(extras!=null){
            if(extras.getString("table")!=null){
                String table=extras.getString("table");

                if(extras.getString("where")!=null){
                    String where =extras.getString("where");
                    if(extras.getString("operation").equalsIgnoreCase("update")){
                        syncUpdate(table,where);
                    }else if(extras.getString("operation").equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
                        syncDelete(table,where);
                    }
                }else{
                    synctable(table);
                }

            }else if(extras.getString("download")!=null){
                download();
            }else{
                syncperiodic();
            }
        }else{
            syncperiodic();
        }

    }
```

Comment: *Is it okay to use a variable in syncadapter* ... no ... it's not ... it's not persistant

Comment: do   android:allowParallelSyncs="false" solve the issue?

Comment: no ... when application will be killed you will lost you lastid ... and that's main problem ... there are more problems like you are storing only one id and seems to have multiple tables

Comment: also ... this is terrible ide to send every "sync message" to `onPerformSync` ... you should rather store changes in database and do batch operation in `onPerformSync` ... seriously it would be better to find existing solution for syncing db instead writting own ... it's really pain in the a...

Comment: i am saving the last synced id in a table in local database. this variable is just to take that value from database. what is your opinion about fetching data from database inside the sync methods i specified in the code? is it okay?